# Filter and read dataset from SQL server into R

Tags: sql, r, odbc, rodbc, large-data

I have a large table in SQL server and would like to import into R with a WHERE clause on date.

```
library(RODBC)
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=mysqlhost;database=mydbname;trusted_connection=true')

# Main table query works well
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from Main')

# I would like to filter it by date column
res <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from Main where Date > '2010-01-01'')
```

Comment: You are probably having problems with the single quotes. You have to escape them. There is nothing wrong with your query @Prasanth

Comment: Or use double-quotes on the outside: `"select * from Main where Date > '2010-01-01';"`

Comment: You might also need to use `[Date]`. I believe Date is a reserved word in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from Main where Date > "'"2010-01-01"'"')

Answer (score 1):

One way you can avoid dealing with the quotes is to use a parameterized query.

```
library (RODBCext)
sqlExecute (
  dbhandle,
  'select * from Main where [Date] > ?',
  list (date = '2010-01-01'),
  fetch = TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```